# Modify image size in Django

Tags: python, django, image

I have ImageField in my model. Because of people may want to upload big photos. Now I want to modify picture size after uploading as it is on Facebook or other websites which have profile pictures.

this is my `ImageField` description

```
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=avatar_directory_path, null=True, blank=True)
```

and this is `avatar_directory_path` function

```
def avatar_directory_path(instance, filename):

    return 'avatars/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)
```

What can you suggest me ?

Answer (score 1):

If you meant image cropping:

[django-image-cropping](https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping) - allow users crop their avatar by themself.

If just want to crop images to fixed size or reduce quality - [pilkit](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/pilkit)